# Synonym for ApprovalWorkflow

Tags: c#, java, c++

We have an abstract workflow class that is called **ApprovalWorkflow** the thing is it can hold both an approve, reject and input state. Its slightly misleading to call it ApprovalWorkflow but I cant be sure of what the right term is.

Does anyone know of a better term to call ApprovalWorkflow as it can Authorize and Reject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem. Authorization can have two outcomes, Authorized and NotAuthorized = Rejected. That's the entire point of it, in fact.

I'm more worried about the input state part. That sounds like [`{True, False, FileNotFound}`](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx)

Comment: It uses the State Pattern for a small workflow (Entered, Approved, Rejected) ... but thanks for the Dilbert .. made my "Friday" :)